# "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Music.check_queue' was never awaited", even though it is

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

for some reason I'm having a problem with this function of mine:

```
async def check_queue(self, ctx):
    if len(self.queueList) > 1:
        await Music.play(self, ctx, self.queueList.pop(0))

    else:
        await ctx.send("No more songs left in the queue")
```

for some reason, every time I call this function, it tells me that it's not awaited, even though it is. I'm quite confused by this error and I don't really know what to do at this point.

That's how I call the function:
`vc.play(source, after=lambda x=None: self.check_queue(ctx))`

any help would be much appriaicated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't appear to be `await`-ing on the `check_queue` method. Maybe you want `vc.play(source, after=lambda x=None: await self.check_queue(ctx))`? Hard to tell without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that as well. It just returns an error, saying that I can't await that outside of an async function (even though this function is also asynced)

Comment: That's what I mean by "hard to tell without seeing more of your code". If you would update the question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's more likely that we can help you out.